# Alpaca forms, one radio button per field

Tags: radio-button, alpacajs

I'm using Alpaca, and I'm having a problem.
I've got several field, pre-filled with JSON data. Some of thoses fields are on readOnly, so I can't modify them, BUT, I would like to have the possibility to "unlock" them and modify them. For this I would like to associate a radio button to each field, representing if the field is locked or not.
Problem is I got no idea how to associate a radio button to each field, and I don't even knwo if this is possible !

I hope that you guys, will be able to help me !:)

Answer (score 0):

PARTIAL SOLUTION :

I'm able to associate a button to each field, using a custom template. It's working properly except when it comes to retrieve the value. Doing a $("#div").alpaca("get").getValue() will return original value, values that have been loaded with the field, but not the modified value.

To get more details about this problem : [StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373677/alpaca-getvalue-not-working-on-costum-template)

And here comes the templates code :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="input-group-addon-template">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="{{inputType}}" value="{{data}}" id="{{id}}" {{#if options.placeholder}}placeholder="{{options.placeholder}}"{{/if}} {{#if options.size}}size="{{options.size}}"{{/if}} {{#if options.readonly}}readonly="readonly"{{/if}} {{#if name}}name="{{name}}"{{/if}} {{#each options.data}}data-{{@key}}="{{this}}"{{/each}} {{#each options.attributes}}{{@key}}="{{this}}"{{/each}}/>
        <div class="input-group-btn" id="{{id}}-basic-btn"> 
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="{{id}}-button" onclick="test(event)" >
            <i {{#if options.readonly}}class="fa fa-lock"{{else}}class="fa fa-unlock"{{/if}}></i> 
        </button>
       </div>
   </div>
</script>
```

And to use it, I'm using the option of alpaca :

```
$("#object_details").alpaca({
                "schema": ...,
                "data": ...,
                "options": {
                    "view": {
                        "templates": {
                            "control-text":"#input-group-addon-template"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```